# Response code for Rest API creating different resource

Tags: rest, http

If my REST API creates a resource different from the intended one, what should be the appropriate status code? Should it still be 201 with the body containing created resource? This is a valid resource only and so, I can't assign error code.
I am new to REST and so, please bear this if it is a naive question.My actual doubt is that client asks me to create X but I create Y instead. So,should I use different response code?

Scenario:

I possess a REST API responsible for transferring an amount from account A to account B, and we denote the resource representing this transaction as X. Additionally, we have another distinct REST API solely designed to hold the amount from account A, and we refer to the resource representing this holding operation as Y.

In certain scenarios, the former API will simply hold the amount by generating resource Y instead of creating resource X. In such a situation, what should be the appropriate response code? I am unable to identify a suitable response code for this specific use case.

Comment: So what's wrong with 201? Maybe even use 200 as "ok, operation completed"

Comment: What is wrong with the question? I am new to the REST space and I had this doubt. I couldn't find any relevant questions in StackOverflow for this. Hence, asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP status codes are metadata of the [transfer-of-documents-over-a-network domain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s).  You should not expect to be leaning on them to communicate domain specific semantics.

> In certain scenarios, the former API will simply hold the amount by generating resource Y instead of creating resource X. In such a situation, what should be the appropriate response code?

Was the request successfully processed?  Did it create a new resource?  Then you RFC 2119 SHOULD return a 201 Created response which includes a Location header that identifies the primary resource created.  See [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-post).

(As far as I can tell, you probably won't inflict unintended harm by choosing to response with a 200 instead of a 201.  But the spec has used equivalent language for 25+ years, so you should make sure that a deviation from the standard is worth it.)

Information describing *which* successful outcome occurred would normally appear in the response body (aka the representation that describes the status of the request), but in some cases might instead be communicated via [web linking](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288).

Comment: Thanks! I am new to REST and so, I had this doubt. My actual doubt is that client asks me  to create X but I create Y instead. So, I thought this should be communicated using REST code